# Why does my c++ program check not initialized variables?

Tags: c++, performance

I'm coding in c++ because I want my program to run fast (the faster the better).

But I am disapointed at the fact that it checks whether a variables is initialized or not...
I don't want it to lose time doing it, even if it is just a nanosecond.

I use VS, and I thought that maybe if I run my program in the not-debug mode it would avoid the check. But it does the check anyway, and shows me a window with this message:
Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'carryingResourceAux' is being used without being initialized.

This line that seems to be generating the error is:
carryingResource = carryingResourceAux;

Can I avoid this check to make my program run slightly faster??

Comment: Could you demonstrate in as few lines as possible what you're talking about, via a [mcve]? Do you mean `carryingResourceAux` is uninitialised? That's UB to use it

Comment: C++ does not check if variables are initialized. That is coming from a VS' sanitizer that is only used if you say so. Which, by the way, is telling you that you have a bug: why are you even trying to read an uninitialized variable?

Comment: Checking whether a variable is uninitialized in an _optimized_ build will not happen and will not cause any loss in performance. It is however a dangerous thing to use an uninitialized variable and you should certainly avoid it. Leave such micro-optimizations to the compiler by all means, and write correct code whenever you can.

Comment: *Can I avoid this check to make my program run slightly faster??* -- Your program has a bug.  What good is a fast program if it has such an obvious bug?

Comment: *and will not cause any loss in performance* -- But may cause bugs due to the optimizer making assumptions about using the uninitialized variable, and thus create really wild program.

Comment: "I'm coding in c++ because I want my program to run fast" Writing something in C or C++ will not magimatically make it "fast".

Answer (score 3):

This check is enabled by the `/RTCu` compiler option.  In the IDE, under project properties -> C/C++ compiler -> Basic Runtime Checks, change the option to not include these checks.  Note that they are only compatible with no optimization (debug builds).

You should optimize your release build, and leave this check in for debug builds.